# My webview is not working on api level 29 - why?

Tags: android, webview

My code here.
 It is working on API 28.
But in API 29 it is not working.
So what is the problem?
Please help me. Advance thanks for all.
I am new in android studio.
So please answer clearly.
Thanks...

```
    superProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.myProgressBar);
    superLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
    webView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewId);


    superProgressBar.setMax(100);
    webView.loadUrl("https://sportscollection9.blogspot.com/2019/11/bpl-live.html");
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            superLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            superLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description,  String failing) {
            webView.loadUrl("Error");
        }
    });
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
            superProgressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
            super.onReceivedTitle(view, title);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: "it is not working" -- could you explain this in greater detail? What exactly are you seeing?

Comment: web page not available

Answer (score 1):

Load url after setting the web view client and settings
for example

```
mWebView.setFocusable(true);
mWebView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Then

```
mWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com");
```

Comment: Hi @Cosmas, What kind of WebViewClient setting needed?

Comment: @meekash55 I have updated my answer .Kindly check it